# implement select/cut/paste in TextArea

Tags: textarea, codenameone

How can I implement the tradition menu items to copy / cut / paste / selectAll
in Codenameone TextArea

I can do these things if I happen to remember the keystrokes, but I don't
see any hooks to do them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since on-device editing is native the cut/copy/paste work thru touch and the menu will implicitly appear. So normally you wouldn't want to do this programmatically in Codename One, e.g. right now we don't have any API to get the currently selected text either since that concept is pretty different between platforms.

There are `Display.copyToClipboard` & `Display.getPasteDataFromClipboard` but those aren't for the text field selection purpose. They are rather for the use case of moving data within/between apps.